# Dynamic Queries with Expressions based on runtime

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core and .NET 5.0.

My repository has a method such as this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Report>> GetByAsync(Expression<Func<Report, bool>> expression)
{
    return await DbSet.Where(expression).ToListAsync();                                            
}
```

I wanted to implement a `Service`'s method as follows:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ReportResponse>> GetByAsync(int? productId, int? brandId, int? modelId, int? lineId, DateTime from, DateTime to)
{
   var reports = await _repository.GetByAsync(
                                 r => r.ProductId == productId && 
                                      r.BrandId == brandId &&
                                      r.ModelId == modelId && 
                                      r.LineId == lineId &&
                                      r.Date >= from && r.Date <= to); 
  // other staff        
}
```

**UPDATE**

Wanted to get result, instead of creating separate methods, based on input has value or not.

For example:

```
GetByAsync(1, null, null, null, '2022-05-01', '2022-06-01')
```

should ignore types that have no values.

And:

```
var reports = await _repository.GetByAsync(r => r.ProductId == 1 && r.Date >= '2022-05-01' && r.Date <= '2022-06-01');
```

I tried with [dynamic queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/how-to-use-expression-trees-to-build-dynamic-queries) but could not manage.

Comment: and what exactly needs to be dynamic here? Everything in your code is statically typed from what I see. Anyway you should be aware that you will *never* get **compile**-time-types when you provide the information at **runtime**. Everything you do will allways just return `object`.

Comment: yes, you are rigth, how can I build expression query like that: `GetBy(1, null, null, null, '2022-05-01', '2022-06-01')` make to equalent to => `r.productId == 1 && r.Date >= '2022-05-01' && r.Date <= '2022-06-01`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you need is some sort of dynamic predicate builder, you can use this utility class: https://gist.github.com/YoussefSell/ec50f079dd3d1a192ba1f5cd5df2d64d

after you import the PredicateBuilder class to your project, actual implementation will be like this:

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<ReportResponse>> GetByAsync(int? productId,
                                                          int? brandId,
                                                          int? modelId,
                                                          int? lineId,
                                                          DateTime? from,
                                                          DateTime? to)
{
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Report>();

    if (productId.HasValue)
        predicate = predicate.And(p => p.ProductId == productId);

    if (brandId.HasValue)
        predicate = predicate.And(p => p.BrandId== brandId);

    if (modelId.HasValue)
        predicate = predicate.And(p => p.ModelId == modelId);

    if (lineId.HasValue)
        predicate = predicate.And(p => p.LineId == lineId);

    if (from.HasValue)
        predicate = predicate.And(p => p.Date >= from);

    if (to.HasValue)
        predicate = predicate.And(p => p.Date <= to);

    // pass the predicate
    var reports = await _repository.GetByAsync(predicate); 

    // other code ...
}
```